# Python dynamic inheritance

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder if I can somehow do this scenario. I have a Core class that will inherit from some dynamic class, and then pass it and inherits it. maybe with `__init__().super()`, not sure. can someone help?

file1:

```
class Core(T):
    # some logic 
    ...
```

file2:

```
class CustomClass(Core(Logic1)):
     def execute():
         return self.apply() condition else []
```

file3:

```
class CustomClass(Core(Logic2)):
     def execute():
         return self.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your purpose, but I suggest you try to use generics with composition:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic,

T = TypeVar('T')

class Core(Generic[T]):
    logic: T

    def __init__(self, logic: T, ...):
        self.logic = logic
    ...

class CustomClass(Core[Logic1]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Logic1(...))

    def execute():
        return self.apply()
    ....
```